# Can gravlax be hung to dry?

Tags: fish, salmon, curing

If I cure salmon into gravlax as made in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0n_jfydU4U) video featuring a Gordon Ramsey recipe, what would happen if I hung the cured salmon for let's say a week after curing has been done. Of course, hanging it in a suitable environment away from lecherous insects.

Ultimately, I want to make a salmon version of [bokkoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokkoms).

Comment: Gravlax is a wet cure, salting and sun drying is a dry cure @NeilMeyer. You need the right conditions to dry cure.

Comment: I tend to think that people here worry too much about botulinum... but you really REALLY don't want to be inventing your own recipes for dried fish.

Comment: There are  lots of other kinds of food poisioning that are more common that botulism.  And if you hang gravlax for a week, you'll get to find all of them!

Comment: It's impolite to make serious changes to your question after someone's already answered your original question. You should roll back your edits, and start a new question instead.

Comment: @NeilMeyer you unfortunately changed the premise, thus effectively making the existing answer “not an answer”. Please don’t do that. I made a rollback (and a bit of cleanup), because a Q/A with an answer that basically says “don’t do that because...” is still helpful, also for future readers. I recommend a new question (you can still link to this one, if you like), asking about the dry cure approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd strongly advice against that. A cure only works as long as the salt and sugar concentrations are high enough. And although Gravlax does a decent job of infusing the salmon with both the content in the salmon itself is not nearly high enough to keep it preserved, it is the crust on the fish itself that keeps it ok to eat.

It is not a problem to keep your salmon under its crust for a week, just make sure to keep it on a rack so liquid can drain away.

What you could try is making a version of [Stockfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stockfish) but you'll need a dry and cool environment (like Norwegian cool). Stockfish is usually made with very lean fish, I don't know how that would work with fatty salmon. But a casual google seems to confirm people are making something called "salmon jerky" so it might just work.

Comment: Making salmon jerky requires dry heat for hours. The traditional method is staking it near an open fire.  Salmon on its own won't dry, it's too fatty.  I'll spoil instead.